# How to expose simple web service using Basic Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I maintain an ASP.NET Web API project which supports a simple REST end point for clients to post XML data to our server. This site is setup to support BasicAuthentication and works very well. All of our security checks are done at the network firewall and on the machine itself using custom Windows User accounts. Recently, one of our clients requires that we support a SOAP end point to receive the XML data as well.

My thought was to simply add a new WebService (Blah.svc) with supporting interface having the required `[ServiceContract]` and `[OperationContract]` attributes to my interface. I had hoped that I could simply expose the URL to our client and it would "just work". I ***am*** able to hit the end point, but this service is not able to extract the user name.

Here is my sample code:

```
public string CreateWorkItem(string xml)
{
    var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        userName = "NO USER NAME";

    var elem = XElement.Parse(xml);
    return $"Hello [{userName}]! You sent [{elem.Value}].";
}
```

Here are my results:

[image: Soap call shows no user name]

I've scoured the web to try and find out how to get access to the BasicAuthentication details in a Soap message, but I'm not having any luck. All the examples that I'm finding require that I create a new WCF project and expose it with a lot of web.config settings, or the examples are ~5 years old using older techniques.

I'd like this service to simply publish with my WebAPI project using the **Publish...** option inside Visual Studio. Unfortunately, I've not found a common denominator to make it work. I'm sure I'm missing something, and I hope someone can help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link out: [WCF Services and ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx)

In short you need to enable [ASP.NET Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx) in your WCF service.

However, you may want to look into using OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.*

Comment: +1 for the link and the tip. Thanks! I am fully consumed in reading this article right now to see how WCF and ASP.NET work together. I will report back soon...

Comment: Thanks again for the links! After diving into this more, I realized that this was the information I needed all along. I didn't realize how much effort went into making WCF and ASP.NET to work seamlessly with one another. I was fighting against the grain the whole way. I will update my post to explain how I ultimately extracted the basic authentication information from the `HttpContext.Current` inside of the soap method.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that it is `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is returning `null` means either:

1. User is `null`; or
2. User is `Anonymous`

I have a few ideas to help resolve the issue.

### 1. Your `User.Name` is actually `null`

You might want to debug by grabbing `HttpContext.Current.User` and see if it's correct.

### 2. Go direct: get the cookie via a parameter

Try and pass the HttpContext as a parameter so you can grab the cookie?

```
public string CreateWorkItem(HttpContext context, string xml)
{
    var username = context.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    ...
}
```

### 3. Your configurations are not setup properly

The alternative is that maybe your `web.config` or `Global.asax` is not setup to properly.

Comment: This is not what I'm wanting. This isn't even supported as far as I can see. When updating my interface and method to test this, it throws many errors. The requirement is that the end-point can only send the `string xml` parameter. I want to get the username from basic authentication bindings somehow.

Comment: I think you are missing something here. I can't put the HttpContext type in the parameter list without wrapping it in a `[DataContract]` attribute. There is a way to pass credentials to the soap message and I just need to figure that out. My issue is #3, my configuration is not setup properly and I need help figuring that out. Thanks anyway. :)